# jquery Isotope Toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle, jquery-isotope

I have an Isotope based Design. 
The itemSelector is clickable an should toggle (slidedown) a hidden element inside. 
Then the isotope-Container shold NOT compleatly reLayout, only slip-down in the Column the Element is.

To better describe my wish I had created 2 images.

Here all elements are closed
[Image 1](http://rhodesign.ch/iso1.jpg)

Here Element 6 is open and only the second column should be higher
[enter link description here](http://rhodesign.ch/iso2.jpg)

Here I have some code I use so far. That code works so far, but reLayout the whole Conatiner compleatly.

```
// change size of clicked element

$container.find('.team').live('click', function() {
if ($(this).is('.large')) {
jQuery('.teaminfo', this).fadeToggle(350, "linear");

$(this).toggleClass('large');
$container.isotope('reLayout');

} else {

jQuery('.large > .teaminfo');
$container.find('.large').removeClass('large');

jQuery('.teaminfo', this).fadeToggle(350, "linear");

$(this).toggleClass('large');
$container.isotope('reLayout');

}
});
```

If anyone can give me a hint i would be very grateful.
Thank you
Roman

Answer (score 0):

To just push down growing boxes in a column you don't need Isotope ;)

Maybe [this type of functionality](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-column-shift.html) of the plugin can be changed to your needs.